# Programmatically define system.web/compilation tag on WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-config, system.web

I'm trying to define all my WCF service configuration in code, I just finished to do it with the system.servicemodel section and I got it right. But I want to set debug attribute on true from the compile section (it's a self hosted service):

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
```

I already did this, but I don't know where to add it in order to make it work:

```
Dim webConf As New System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection
webConf.Debug = True
webConf.Strict = False
webConf.TargetFramework = "4.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly in your startup method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.aspx

Comment: The example you refer to, uses the web.config file; I want to know how to (if it's possible) to define it just from code without using it.